# Not sure, why this code, while scanning the dynamically allocated array causing segmentation fault

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic-arrays

Trying to read the dynamically allocated two dimensional array.
but having segmentation fault. cannot find out why. as of my understanding, it should work

while scanning the array. on first input, it causes segmentation fault

```
class DiognalSum
{
public :
 int **a;
public :
 DiognalSum(int n)
 {
  int **a = new int*[n];
  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
   a[i] = new int[n];
  }
 }
public :
   void getArray(int n)
   {
     int input;
     for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
     {
      for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
      {
       cin >> input;
       a[i][j] = input; // segmentation fault is here
      }
     }
   }
   void printArray(int n)
   {
      cout << "Out " << endl;
      for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
     {
      for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
      {
        cout << a[i][j];
      }
        cout << endl;
     }

    }
};

int main()
{
 DiognalSum d(3);
 d.getArray(3);
 d.printArray(3);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please add tag with programming language used

Answer (score 4):

```
DiognalSum(int n)
 {
  //int **a = new int*[n];  // <-- you have locally declared `int **a`

  a = new int*[n];  // <-- correct would be to use DiognalSum::a
  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
   a[i] = new int[n];
  }
 }
```

Comment: Maybe even do `DiognalSum(int n) : a(new int*[n])` to avoid such mistakes. As in, when writing a constructor, make a habit of always creating an initializer list with all member variables in it.

Comment: @Lundin that's like putting a band aid on an axe wound ... RAII should be used for this allocation set

Comment: @Lundin: `all member variables in it` or mostly which can be completely initialized? I mean half initialization in list and half inside constructor can be little difficult to maintain.

Comment: Well, obviously it is better not to fiddle with these things manually. But for the generic case, it is good practice to include all _member variables that are primitive data types_ ("POD") in the initializer list. Of course objects with constructors of their own need not necessarily be there.

Comment: @Lundin `all member variables` is better. `MyClass::MyClass(...) : member(member_arg, member_arg2) {}` uses an appropriate constructor for `member`. The normal case is using the copy constructor for the appropriate type, that's all